# dynamic display php javascript

Tags: programming

I am looking at a couple different e-Commerce solutions. One is WooCommerce and Magento is the other. The website I want to develop would access a database of cities, flights, tourist itineraries, and restaurants. The user would fill out a survey to determine what type of vacation they would like, food likes and dislikes, activity likes, etc., and the website would take their answers and spit out a vacation package unique to them, complete with flights, pictures, restaurant names, etc. Is this possible using Magento? Or is the programmatic logic to determine how to dynamically display a vacation package based on user input and database content outside the scope of Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Is this possible using Magento? 
-Yes

Or is the programmatic logic to determine how to dynamically display a vacation package based on user input and database content outside the scope of Magento?
-Yes

Magento is a very robust ecommerce platform, but that is what it is, an ecommerce platform. You could use many of magento's features for this proposed website.

In regards to your question whether or not the website you described is out of Magento's scope, I would say yes, as it is not a typical ecommerce business with a structured catalog of products with attributes. However, many ecommerce businesses utilize magento beyond its scope.

Anything is possible if you are a skilled programmer.